# Python formating 'dd-MMM-yyyy HH-mm' to python datetime

Tags: python, datetime, format

I have format string `dd-MMM-yyyy HH-mm` to python readable format.
Need to use like this:

```
format = 'dd-MMM-yyyy HH-mm'
datetime.datetime.strptime(request.data.get('date'), format)
```

This is not python format by default, i need to convert it.

Any library for this, or snippet?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Are you just looking for the Python time format for that specific format string, or are you asking for, like, a general algorithm to convert all non-Python time format strings into Python time format strings? If it's the first one, couldn't you just figure it out from the documentation?

Comment: I need to convert all non-Python to python date time format. @Kevin

Comment: Python format is at [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: But i need to convert it, not how to use python format.

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas for this

```
import pandas
pd.to_datetime(request.data.get('date'))
```

Since your datetime is already in standard format you don't even need to specify format

See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html for more info

Comment: But i need custom format, `H-m` that is `hour-minute` so this library is not really for this.